# Why do Americans use ‘them’ in a certain awkward sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, subcontinental-english, possessive-pronouns

So, I am not a native English speaker. I am from India and some of the sentences that I hear from certain movies leave me dumbfounded.

So, the other day I was watching Suicide Squad and I heard Will Smith say, "So, you one of them deaf hoes?" Now, what is that supposed to mean?

Let me make one thing clear: I do know the meaning of *hoe* (cough).

Comment: This is probably better on ELL rather than ELU. But a quick answer is it's just slang. The "correct" sentence should be "So, you are on of those deaf hoes?".

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate of some old well-received post.

Comment: Lemme guess.  Will Smith is playing a cop, and he approaches a street-walker for information, and she is acting as if she doesn't even hear him.  This is street talk.

Comment: @NVZ I am pretty sure it isn't.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150674/using-them-instead-of-those

Comment: @Abhishekstudent This type of usage is in the dictionary: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/them See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_do_you_like_them_apples