# Meaning of "them as can't, teach"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

What is the meaning and grammar of **“them as can’t”** in the following text:

> "Them as can, do; them as can't, teach." Alas, more teachers fall into this category than ever before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common proverb:

***[Those who can, do; those who can't, teach.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Those+who+can%2C+do%3B+those+who+can%27t%2C+teach)***

> Prov. People who are able to do something well can do that thing for a living, while people who are not able to do anything that well make a living by teaching. (Used to disparage teachers. From George Bernard Shaw's Man and Superman.)
>
> - Bob: I'm so discouraged. My writing teacher told me my novel is hopeless. Jane: Don't listen to her, Bob. Remember: those who can, do; those who can't, teach.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

For the use of ***them*** see ***[Using “them” instead of “those”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150674/using-them-instead-of-those).***

Comment: I think the usage of *as* here is probably more opaque than the usage of *them* (and I have the impression they're linked—i.e. "them as" is a more likely collocation than either "those as" or "them who"—but I don't know if that's correct). Maybe you could go into more detail on that bit?

Comment: Thanks. Can you also clarify the use of "as" instead of "who"?

Comment: @ib11 - it appears to be a common collocation as in: *Them as has, gits*.
Rur. Rich people can always get more. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Them+as+has%2C+gits

Answer (score 0):

It is northern England dialect, most likely Yorkshire.

*Them as has/he as can/we as know* = Those that have/he that can/We that know.

As @user240918 points out, it is an idiomatic saying, a kind of folk wisdom, especially in northern England.