# What is the meaning of "them" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

In Leon the Professional, Leon put a knife over a rich man's neck and the rich man said this to him.

> Hey, relax, man. I got half of Bolivia sitting in them suitcases over
>   here.

What's the meaning of "them" and can you give other examples using it?

Comment: it's a colloquialism for "in those suitcases".

Comment: please see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150674/using-them-instead-of-those The use of 'them' rather than 'those' is correct in some dialects of both American and British English. it is only incorrect according to the dialect called standard English. (also, as I recall, the movie in question is in French with English subtitles, so I can only guess that the ppl who wrote the subtitles wanted to convey a non-standard type of speaking in French by using a non standard way of speaking in English)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "them" instead of "those"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150674/using-them-instead-of-those)

Answer (score 1):

This is just ungrammatical English. What he should have said is

> Hey, relax, man. I got half of Bolivia sitting in **those** suitcases over here.

This misuse is frequently heard particularly in [Cockney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney) which is a dialect spoken in East London, traditionally by those born within earshot of Bow Bells (St Mary-le-Bow church). It is often associated with the working classes. The difference between **them and those** is answered over in ELL by [this Q&A](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26509/difference-between-and-usage-of-them-and-these-those)

Comment: I wonder if it is also used that way in working class America...

Comment: So, it’s not ungrammatical in the dialects where it is used. It’s just non-standard.

Comment: @MartinF it's certainly used in media depictions of working class American speech.

Comment: why should someone speaking a dialect other than standard English speak according to that (latter) dialect

Comment: @green_ideas - That's a huge topic. Maybe you should ask it as a question, though i suspect it has already been asked and answered in many ways. I'll just say that standard English is constantly changing, and it's because so many people break the rules so often.

Comment: Martin, perhaps you miss my point. the use of 'them' is not ungrammatical in some dialects of both American and British English, so this answer should be clarified to that effect. thus the speaker, speaking different dialect than the dialect called Standard English is speaking grammatically in his dialect and should not have said 'those'